# Delete last character of last item in a bash array

Tags: bash, array

I have such array:

```
Array={123},{456}
```

Now I want to delete the last item `6`.

Comment: To remove last element in array you can use `unset Array[6]` for 7th element or `unset Array[-1]` for the last. But are you sure that is the array?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. However, `sed 's/.}$/}/' <<< "$Array"`

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in `bash` are defined like:

```
a=(foo bar baz)
```

Or:

```
a=([12]=foo [5]=bar)
```

(arrays in `bash` are more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive numbers and with elements sorted on those numerically).

To delete the last character of the element with the greatest key, with recent versions of `bash`, you'd do:

```
a[-1]=${a[-1]%?}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not an array, it is just a variable named `Array`. To remove **next to last** character of that variable you can play with substring expansion, e.g.:

```
$ Array={123},{456}
$ echo "${Array:0:${#Array}-2}${Array:${#Array}-1}"
{123},{45}
```

Here `${#Array}` denotes number of characters of the variable string.

Comment: Alternatively just "${Array::-2}}"

Comment: Other variant with variable if element is unique: `${Array/${Array: -2:1}/}`. In modern bash version: `${Array:0:-2}${Array: -1}`. **Don't miss spaces**